# how can I get path list folder Android and set in Int Array.

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, pageviews

I'm new in Android sorry....

I save any pictures in my App not SDCARD.

I use this code for get path but this code return String Array, I need return Int Array for my class CustomSwipeAdpter, this class for Page View.

```
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // path to data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        new_folder = cw.getDir(pasta, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ArrayList<String> arquivos = new ArrayList<String> ();

        if (!new_folder.exists()){
            new_folder.mkdir();
        }
        // verifica a pasta se tem arquivo //
        File[] files = new_folder.listFiles();

        if ((files.length > 0)) {
            String[] fileArray = new String[files.length];
            int[] fileArrayInt = new int[files.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
                fileArray[i] = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
            }
            //filesResource[i] = Integer.parseInt(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
```

I will get this paths in this Class In Page View, this class is work with R.drawable.image01, i need change for my paths...

```
public class CustomSwipeAdpter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03,
        R.drawable.image04, R.drawable.image05, R.drawable.image06, R.drawable.image07, R.drawable.image08};

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Resources resource;

public CustomSwipeAdpter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    resource = ctx.getResources();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(resource,
                    image_resources[position],
                    1080,
                    2560));

    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}


public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 2;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

This class is fine when i use:

```
 private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03,
        R.drawable.image04, R.drawable.image05, R.drawable.image06, R.drawable.image07, R.drawable.image08};
```

I need set this image_resources the my path.

Answer (score 0):

May you could try follow way instead of resources:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileArray[position]);
```